# Adding post form action in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I've having a hard time using the post form function in html/ laravel to go back to the index page from the list page.

```
<form method="post" action="HomeController@index" >
</form>
```

My routes is:

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@index');
Route::post('/', array('uses' => 'HomeController@index'));
Route::get('/list', 'ListController@list');
```

The error I get is

```
TokenMismatchException
```

And I notice that the URL  only adds the Controller in the index posts
http://localhost/mylaravel/list/HomeController@index

When it should be 
http://localhost/mylaravel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this way..

```
<form action="{{ url('/') }}" method="post">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="text" name="title">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add csrf token in your form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="HomeController@index" >
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <!-- other code -->
</form>
```

Or:

```
<form method="post" action="HomeController@index" >
    @csrf

    <!-- other code -->
</form>
```

For Laravel 4:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token() ?>">
```

Comment: It does not seem to work. I tried enclosing it in a php tag, it still displayed the token mismatch error? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which Laravel version you are using? If you are using <5.5 you should use `{{ csrf_field() }}`

Comment: its laravel 4. I tried the {{csrf_field()}} it shows an error MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token() ?>">` -> This should work on Laravel 4!

Comment: Hi it still returned a MethodNotAllowedHttpException error for some reason?

Comment: Do `action="/"` in your form directly and let me know if it works!

Comment: As you stated that `Route::post('/', array('uses' => 'HomeController@index'));`! The action should goto the `/`! Or try `Route::post('/', 'HomeController@index');`. I can help you this much only!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Laravel official doc version 5.7](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf), Laravel automatically generates a CSRF "token" for each active user session managed by the application. Anytime you define a HTML form in your application, you should include a hidden CSRF token field in the form so that the CSRF protection middleware can validate the request.

```
<form method="POST" action="action="{{ action('MailboxController@store') }}">

     // Use this blade directive to generate the token field
     @csrf

     <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="To:">
     </div>
     ...
     ...
```

The VerifyCsrfToken middleware will automatically verify this token after matching this requested token with stored token in session.